# How to delete rows based on like, but but not for every like statement

Tags: mysql, sql-like, sql-delete

I have a table in my MySQL named Animals in which the description column has the values such as

| Id | description | age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Animal is Cat | 14 |
| 2 | Animal is Dog | 3 |
| 3 | Animal is Tiger | 5 |
| 4 | Animal is Bat | 12 |
| 5 | Animal is Rat | 8 |
| 6 | Animal is Squirrel | 13 |
| 7 | Animal is Cat | 4 |
| 8 | Dog | 13 |
| 9 | Tiger | 15 |

I need to delete those rows which doesn't have the description values  Cat, Bat and Squirrel  when the description is starting with 'Animal is ' and whose age is above 12 or equal to 12

Which means, I need to only remove the rows whose description only starts with 'Animal is' but I don't want to delete it for 'Animal is cat', 'Animal is Bat', 'Animal is Squirrel'

| Id | description | age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Animal is Cat | 14 |
| 4 | Animal is Bat | 12 |
| 6 | Animal is Squirrel | 13 |
| 8 | Dog | 13 |
| 9 | Tiger | 15 |

I've tried doing,

```
DELETE FROM animals WHERE description LIKE 'Animal is%' and Age >=12;
```

But that seems to be removing all the rows, and I'd like to keep the values of cat, bat and Squirrel.

Comment: I'd expect any solution to contain the words cat, bat, and squirrel. Why do you not think so?

Comment: And for further help, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: If you have any other solutions, I'll take it.

Answer (score 0):

To select the records you want you can use these conditions:

```
age >= 12 AND 
  ((description NOT LIKE 'Animal is%') OR (description LIKE '%Cat') OR 
                                           (description LIKE '%Bat') OR 
                                           (description LIKE '%Squirrel'))
```

So, you can delete all other rows by applying `NOT` to the above:

```
DELETE FROM animals 
WHERE
  NOT (
        age >= 12 AND 
        ((description NOT LIKE 'Animal is%') OR (description LIKE '%Cat') OR  
         (description LIKE '%Bat') OR (description LIKE '%Squirrel'))
      )
```

[Demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e5d0ee/1)

Comment: I forgot to add one crucial condition, I have edited the question again, can you help me out?

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to filter the rows having the description that starts with "Animal is" and then, from those rows, I am excluding the results which are specific for cat, bat, squirrel. Note that columns like 'Animal is cat cat' or "Animal is cat bat" or "Animal is cat monkey" would be deleted as well.

```
DELETE FROM animals where description like 'Animal is%' and description NOT REGEXP '^Animal is Cat|Animal is Bat|Animal is Squirrel$' and age>=12;
```

Comment: I've edited the question a little bit, can you help me with the edited one?

Comment: The community encourages adding explanations alongisde code, rather than purely code-based answers (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)).